# for object in collection where object inherits

Tags: objective-c, syntax, foreach, language-features

In objective-c, is

```
for (Foo *foo in fooList) ...
```

more like which of the following

```
@interface Bar : Foo ...

for (Foo *f in fooList) {
    // A:
    if ([f isMemberOfClass:[Foo class]]) ... // dont include Bar's

    // B:
    if ([f isKindOfClass:[Foo class]]) ... // both Foos and Bars
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not like either.

The type of `foo` in the `for()` part is only a hint to the compiler so it can give out the relevant error messages.  At run time, all the objects are just objects and as long as they all implement the methods used in the block, there will be no errors.  For example:

```
NSString* aString = @"20";
[anArray addObject: aString];
for (NSNumber* foo in anArray)
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [foo intValue]);
}
```

will iterate over all the objects in the array and send intValue to each one **no matter what type they are** including the NSString at the end.  If every object implements `intValue` it will work just fine (as NSString does).  If there is an object in the array that does not implement intValue, an exception will most likely be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are asking whether `for (Foo *foo in fooList)` will iterate over the subset of items in `fooList` that are members of class `Foo` or the subset of items that are kind of class `Foo`.

The answer is: None. Fast enumeration (for... in) will iterate over **all the items in the collection**. It will **not** filter the objects of type `Foo`.