# How can we set background color for 1 or more textfields using for loop in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In my project I am adding above "6" textfields on my storyboard and they are "Email","name","Firstname"...etc textfields

now I want to set background color for all this textfields using "For" loop

is it possible to set using for loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781585/iphone-how-to-enumerate-through-uitextfields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enumerate through UITextFields on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781585/how-to-enumerate-through-uitextfields-on-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it purely in code like this:

```
NSArray *textFields = @[self.emailTextField, self.nameTextField, self.firstNameTextField ... etc];
for (UITextField *textField in textFields) {
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Alternatively you can create an `IBOutletCollection` in your storyboard and hook it up all text fields to a single property on your view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *textFields;

@end
```

Then iterate of `self.textFields` in a similar manner to my first example.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color in storyboard. as you created those in storyboard which is good practice. But if you created those textfield programatically then it would be good practice to set BG color programatically by a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

if all of your text fields are inside the same view controller, simply add inside the view controller's implementation:

```
for (UITextField *textField in self.view.subviews) {
if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
  textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor exampleColor];
 }
}
```

if they are not in the same view controller, add all of the view controller into an array and do it from there:

```
NSArray *array = @[emailField, nameField, etc...]
    for (UITextField *textField in array)
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor exampleColor];
}
```

Comment: inside the for condition it is indicated that textField is indeed a UITextField, and therefor I believe that it will work.